# How can I create a concatenated message in a SQL Server throw?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have this code:

```
IF (@CurrentResult != 'N' AND @CurrentResult != 'F')
    THROW 50002, 'Question should be unmarked or incorrect', 1
```

Can someone explain to me how I can also give the @CurrentResult in the error message I throw?

What I would like is for the message to appear like:

```
Question result is 'X'. It should be unmarked or incorrect?
```

Where X is the value of @CurrentResult.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You cannot concatenate strings inside a `THROW` statement.

What you need to do is create a variable and assign your whole error message to it:

```
DECLARE @Message NVARCHAR(100)
SET @Message = N'Question result is ''' + @CurrentResult + '''. It should be unmarked or incorrect?'

IF (@CurrentResult != 'N' AND @CurrentResult != 'F')
    THROW 50002, @Message, 1
```

Comment: UserVoice: [Allow String Concatenation in THROW](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/36388567-allow-string-concatenation-in-throw)

Answer (score 3):

Edited to reflect setting message variable first:

```
DECLARE @Message varchar(100)
SET @Message = 'Question result is ' + cast(@CurrentResult, varchar(100)) + '. It should be unmarked or incorrect.'

IF (@CurrentResult != 'N' AND @CurrentResult != 'F')
    THROW 50002,@Message,1
```

Casting to varchar will keep the text value of whatever `@CurrentResult` is. Set the size accordingly.

Comment: It doesn't like the first + in the THROW.  I had initially tried something like this and could not get it to work. I think now maybe the string has to be constructed before the throw. Can I do that with a simple SET and does the right side of the SET have to have a SELECT ?

Comment: Ah, yeah I apologize, I think @roryap answer will work.